# Problem in useContext on react js when I practise Codesandbox! Please

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Here the link https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontex-tha-ewwepl I found the error in the child component. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your main application in the provider you have written. A ton of information can be found at [the react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

```
import "./styles.css";
import Child from "./Child";
import { AppProvider } from "./UserContext";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppProvider>
        <Child />
      </AppProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Decode: ekil dna sknaht